# Gamma random numbers, MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, matlab, gamma

I have this line of code in a MATLAB program:

```
x(:,i) = gamrnd(a(i),1,dim,1)
```

I was wondering in what way I could write this same line in Python. I think the equivalent statement is:

```
gamma.rvs(a, size=1000)
```

However, this keeps giving me an Index Error.

Here is my full code for this part:

```
x = np.array([])
for i in range(N-1):
    # generates dim random variables
    x[:, i] = gamma.rvs(a[i], dim-1)    # generates dim random variables
                                            # with gamma distribution
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post the actual error you're seeing and when it occurs. `gamma.rvs(a, size=1000)` should _just work_.

Comment: The problem is `x[:, i]`. That index doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `x = np.array([])` and then tried accessing `x[:, 0]`, which doesn't exist, hence the `Index Error`. You'll want to append instead:

```
x = np.array([])
for i in range(N-1):
    np.append(x, gamma.rvs(a[i], dim - 1))
```

The documentation for `np.append` can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

Comment: `np.append` is extremely inefficient. Also, this will produce a flat array rather than the shape the questioner is looking for.